# How to serially communicate arduino uno to PIC18f4550?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, communication

I am new in PIC programming

my question is, how can i communicate arduino UNO with  PIC18f4550. i am using [THIS](http://g01.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB11cl0KXXXXXb.XVXXq6xXFXXXZ/-font-b-PIC-b-font-font-b-Development-b-font-font-b-Board-b-font.jpg) programmer board for PIC controller and it has a builtin RS232 serial interface.

Can any body tell me how to communicate between them. I want to communicate in such a way that only Rx & Tx pins and the power pins of arduino will be used.

Answer (score 1):

yeah you can quite easily do the Serial communication between Arduino and PIC Microcontroller. You need to connect the below pins:

- Arduino TX will be connected to PIC RX.
- Arduino RX will be connected to PIC TX.
- GND of Arduino must be connected to GND of PIC.

Next thing you need to remember is to have same baud rate for both Arduino and PIC. Now you should check these two posts:

- [Arduino Serial Communication](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial).
- [PIC Serial Communication](http://learn.mikroe.com/ebooks/picmicrocontrollersprogramminginassembly/chapter/serial-communication-modules/)

First one is explaining the Serial Communication of Arduino while the second one is Serial Communication of PIC Microcontroller. You should also read [What is Serial Port?](http://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2015/06/serial-port.html) to get more idea about Serial communication.

I hope they will help you out. If you still got into some issues then let me know.